# Extra space left by Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The code below leaves a large space when columns are collapsed. Any way to remove them?

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.poster {
  height: 20%;
}
h2,
h3 {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <!--The top-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <img src="mirzapur.jpg" class="poster" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
          <h2>Title:</h2>
          <h3>Mirzapur</h3>
          <br />
          <h2>Ratings:</h2>
          <h3>4/5</h3>
          <br />
          <h2>Number of Seasons:</h2>
          <h3>1</h3>
          <br />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
          <h2>Available On :</h2>
          <h3>Amazon Prime,Netflix</h3>
          <br />
          <h2>Year of release :</h2>
          <h3>4/5</h3>
          <br />
          <h2>Genre:</h2>
          <h3>Crime, Thriller, Action</h3>
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

As you can see in the image above, large amounts of spaces are left between the image and the other details.Any way I can remove those spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue has to be with the image sizing, use `width`  instead of `height` to style how your image occupies the space.

```
.poster {
      /* height: 20%; */
      width: 20%;
    }
```